# Error of 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self' on init in a different module

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have checked questions sharing the same topic but none address this weird behaviour I am experiencing:

Say I have a simple old school `struct`:

```
struct Person {
   var name: String
   var age: Int
}
```

And I want to overload the `init` in an `extension` like this:

```
extension Person {
   init(name: String) {
       self.name = name
       self.age = 26
   }
}
```

As you expected, this code would run just fine.

However, If I move the `Person struct` to a different `module` (a.k.a different framework) and expose it to my module like this:

```
public struct Person {
   public var name: String
   public var age: Int
}
```

If I now overload the `init` in an `extension` locally in my `module` the compiler produces the following errors:

`'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'`

`'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`

The only way I found to avoid this problem is calling the original `init` inside the overloaded one like this:

```
 extension Person {
    init(name: String) {
       self.init(name: name, age: 24)
    }
 }
```

I personally find this behaviour to be pretty strange.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be related to [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2295) post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this example works for me with only a warning saying `Initializer for struct 'Person' must use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." because it is not in module`. As far as I know it was by design that struct initialisers were enforced to be defined within the scope of the struct definition module since Swift 4.2. Check the motivation section in 'https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0189-restrict-cross-module-struct-initializers.md'.